# Reverse progressbar using CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this [**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mils/fmaGZ/1/).

I want to reverse the progress bar 180 degree to progress from right to left. 
To obtain something like this :

[image]

I tried to change the **transition** attribute but no result.

Code :

```
.progress-bar span {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #777;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) inset;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) inset;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) inset;
        transition: width .4s ease-in-out;      
}
```

Comment: transform: rotate(180deg); did the trick for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the progress bar block and just float it to the right:

```
.progress-bar span {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    ...
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fmaGZ/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Make the span a block element and use `margin-left`. But you need to inverse the progress as well. E.g. 30% needs `margin-left:70%`;

http://jsfiddle.net/fmaGZ/2/