# Is it possible to have a progress bar move from right to left based on a negative value in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

Before even embarking on this project, I'd like to know if it's at all possible to reverse the progress bar found in the bootstrap framework, so it can display a value going from right to left? The reason behind this question is that I have a range of numbers that can go from positive to negative. The idea is to place two progress bars next to each other and have the right one display the percentage range when the value is positive, and the left bar to display the percentage range when value is negative. For now, the values are static, but these will be 'live' in the future.

Any input on this, and if possible, a pointer to similar projects? I haven't really found anything relevant done with this framework.

I've looked at posts like this one: [Reverse progressbar using CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017509/reverse-progressbar-using-css3), but I'm not sure if this is the way to go when using Bootstrap. Is there some sort of override available for this kind of functionality, in regards to css?

Right now, my progress bar is setup like so:

```
        <li>Speed<span class="pull-right"><em>@Math.Round(DepthValue, 2) m/min</em></span>
            <div class="progress progress-success">
                <div class="bar" style="width: @Model.SpeedRangePercentage%"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I actually figured it out! :) Turned out to be really easy, and indeed the answer was found in the previously linked post;

```
    <li>Speed<span class="pull-right"><em>@Math.Round(DepthValue, 2) m/min</em></span>
        <div class="progress progress-success">
            <div class="bar" style="width: @Model.SpeedRangePercentage%; display: block; float: right;"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Adding styles "display: block;" and "float; right" caused the bar to move from right to left.

Answer (score 14):

Further to the accepted answer, in Bootstrap 4+, the progress bar now uses Flex, and floating won't work.

So now, do the following (add "**justify-content-end**" ):

```
<div class="progress justify-content-end">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" style="width: 10%" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

In Bootstrap 4 just change the div with class `.progress` to `flex-direction: row-reverse` or use the `flex-row-reverse` helper class (as denoted below):

```
<div class="progress flex-row-reverse">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can adjust an actual progress bar element via CSS in a couple different ways.

```
progress {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

or better yet

```
progress {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I could propose a different option, it's even easier than this. Think about it this way:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width:40%;"></div>
</div>
```

The `.progress` element is a block-level element, so just float or position the `.progress-bar` however you like inside it. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZaLiTHkA/87rmhkr3/) is a quick fiddle of this idea for reference.

Comment: 5 years later to the day, a rep change on SO brought me back to this one... at which point I realised that my "different option" was effectively the same as the accepted answer. I feel like a real bright spark now.. *mini facepalm*

Answer (score 2):

Use `transform: rotate(180deg);` on the progress class.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the margin left auto (.ml-auto) to the progress bar

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar ml-auto" role="progressbar" style="width: 10%" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0"
    aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching background and foreground colors and gradually reducing progress bar value. It might work but it will be VERY confusing.

Comment: I'm not sure that will work, as the range can go from -X% to +Y%. The values will be displayed in two different bars, not the same one :) Visualize them nexto to each other :) (If I understand your comment correctly)

Comment: If range is between -X% and +Y%, then your status bar needs to have range from 0 to X+Y. Just add X every time you update it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple just `interchange the background colors of progress and progress bar`. That way if the progress bar width changes it will look like it is progressing in reverse way. Including the .css style

```
.progress{
  background-color: #007bff;
}

.progress-bar{
  background-color: #e9ecef;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another working solution, tested in Bootstrap 5 is to add dir="rtl" to the main ".progress" div as follows:

```
<div class="progress" dir="rtl">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-label="Example with label" style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```