# How to make the progress bar transit from right-to-left instead of left-to-right?

Tags: html, css

I tried to put a "float:right" in the .skill_item_colored_main_wrap part. but it became such a mess. I think it has something to do with -webkit-animation part. 
how can i modify it so it will transit from right to left?

```css
.shortcode_skill {
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.shortcode_skill:before {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:27%;
 margin:15px 0 0;
 width:1px;
 height:95%;
 background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
 content:"";
}

.skill_item {
 overflow:hidden;
 width:100%;
}

.skill_item > span {
 float:left;
 padding:24px 4.7% 0 0;
 width:25%;
 text-align:right;
}

.skill_item_colored_main_wrap {
 float:left;
 padding:15px 0 5px;
 width:70%;
}

.skill_item_colored_wrap {
 position:relative;
 height:33px;
}

.skill_item_colored {
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 -webkit-animation:move 2s linear .1s normal none 1 ;
 -moz-animation:move 2s linear .1s normal none 1 ;
 -ms-animation:move 2s linear .1s normal none 1 ;
 -o-animation:move 2s linear .1s normal none 1 ;
 animation:move 2s linear .1s normal none 1 ;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
 from {width:0;}
 to {width:100%;}
}

@-ms-keyframes move {
 from {width:0;}
 to {width:100%;}
}

@-o-keyframes move {
 from {width:0;}
 to {width:100%;}
}

@keyframes move {
 from {width:0;}
 to {width:100%;}
}

.skill_item_colored_wrap > span {
 position:relative;
 display:block;
}

.skill_item_colored > span {
 display:block;
 padding:8px 10px;
 text-align:right;
 -webkit-animation:opacity 2.5s linear .1s normal none 1 ;
 -moz-animation:opacity 2.5s linear .1s normal none 1 ;
 -ms-animation:opacity 2.5s linear .1s normal none 1 ;
 -o-animation:opacity 2.5s linear .1s normal none 1 ;
 animation:opacity 2.5s linear .1s normal none 1 ;
}

@-webkit-keyframes opacity {
 0% {opacity:0;}
 90% {opacity:0;}
 100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-moz-keyframes opacity {
 0% {opacity:0;}
 90% {opacity:0;}
 100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-ms-keyframes opacity {
 0% {opacity:0;}
 90% {opacity:0;}
 100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-o-keyframes opacity {
 0% {opacity:0;}
 90% {opacity:0;}
 100% {opacity:1;}
}

@keyframes opacity {
 0% {opacity:0;}
 90% {opacity:0;}
 100% {opacity:1;}
}
```

```html
<div class="skill_item">
<span>hello world </span>
<div class="skill_item_colored_main_wrap">
<div class="skill_item_colored_wrap" style="width:95%;">
<div class="skill_item_colored" style="background-color:#f97a14;">
   <span>95%</span>
      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: This previous [post][1] may help too.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910523/is-it-possible-to-have-a-progress-bar-move-from-right-to-left-based-on-a-negativ

Answer (score 5):

A quick and easy way to do this would be to rotate the parent element `180deg` and then rotate the child element negative `-180deg`.

Assuming you want the text aligned to the left, I added `text-align: left`. Omit that if you want it aligned to the right.

```
.skill_item_colored_wrap {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.skill_item_colored_wrap .skill_item_colored > span {
  text-align: left;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```css
.skill_item_colored_wrap {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.skill_item_colored_wrap .skill_item_colored > span {
  text-align: left;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.shortcode_skill {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.shortcode_skill:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 27%;
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 95%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  content: "";
}
.skill_item {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.skill_item > span {
  float: left;
  padding: 24px 4.7% 0 0;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: right;
}
.skill_item_colored_main_wrap {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 0 5px;
  width: 70%;
}
.skill_item_colored_wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 33px;
}
.skill_item_colored {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: move 2s linear .1s normal none 1;
  -moz-animation: move 2s linear .1s normal none 1;
  -ms-animation: move 2s linear .1s normal none 1;
  -o-animation: move 2s linear .1s normal none 1;
  animation: move 2s linear .1s normal none 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes move {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes move {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes move {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.skill_item_colored_wrap > span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.skill_item_colored > span {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  text-align: right;
  -webkit-animation: opacity 2.5s linear .1s normal none 1;
  -moz-animation: opacity 2.5s linear .1s normal none 1;
  -ms-animation: opacity 2.5s linear .1s normal none 1;
  -o-animation: opacity 2.5s linear .1s normal none 1;
  animation: opacity 2.5s linear .1s normal none 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes opacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes opacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes opacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes opacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes opacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="skill_item">
  <span>hello world </span>
  <div class="skill_item_colored_main_wrap">
    <div class="skill_item_colored_wrap" style="width:95%;">
      <div class="skill_item_colored" style="background-color:#f97a14;">
        <span>95%</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As an alternative, you could also set `direction: rtl` on the `.skill_item` element, and then set the `.skill_item_colored_main_wrap` element's `display` to `inline-block` and remove `float: left`:

```
.skill_item {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  direction: rtl;
}
.skill_item_colored_main_wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
.skill_item {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  direction: rtl;
}
.skill_item_colored_main_wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}
.shortcode_skill {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.shortcode_skill:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 27%;
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 95%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  content: "";
}
.skill_item > span {
  float: left;
  padding: 24px 4.7% 0 0;
  width: 25%;
}
.skill_item_colored_main_wrap {
  padding: 15px 0 5px;
  width: 70%;
}
.skill_item_colored_wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 33px;
}
.skill_item_colored {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: move 2s linear .1s normal none 1;
  -moz-animation: move 2s linear .1s normal none 1;
  -ms-animation: move 2s linear .1s normal none 1;
  -o-animation: move 2s linear .1s normal none 1;
  animation: move 2s linear .1s normal none 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes move {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes move {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes move {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.skill_item_colored_wrap > span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.skill_item_colored > span {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  text-align: right;
  -webkit-animation: opacity 2.5s linear .1s normal none 1;
  -moz-animation: opacity 2.5s linear .1s normal none 1;
  -ms-animation: opacity 2.5s linear .1s normal none 1;
  -o-animation: opacity 2.5s linear .1s normal none 1;
  animation: opacity 2.5s linear .1s normal none 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes opacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes opacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes opacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes opacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes opacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="skill_item">
  <span>hello world </span>
  <div class="skill_item_colored_main_wrap">
    <div class="skill_item_colored_wrap" style="width:95%;">
      <div class="skill_item_colored" style="background-color:#f97a14;">
        <span>95%</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here an alternative,

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width:95%%;"></div>
</div>
```

And add this to your `CSS`

```
.progress-middle .progress-bar {
    position: relative;
}
.progress-right .progress-bar {
    float: right;
}
```

What we did here is make sure the position is `relative` then float the `progress-bar` to right instead of `left`.